# Best practice for script caching with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

Using: 
C# MVC5 and Jquery

I have a filter screen that potentially uses multiple different filters. Based on what the user selects I make a call to the server and I load a partial view into a bootstrap modal as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: filterUrl,
            contentType: 'application/html',
            success: function (filterContent) {
                $("#divReportFilterModalBody").html(filterContent);
                LoadFilterScript(SCOPESTRINGS[currentReport.Scope]);
            },....
```

The next step is to load the necessary javascript for that filter page because you cant have scripts on a partial view. For this I also request the script from the server as follows:

```
 $.getScript(scopeString + "FilterJavaScript",
            function () {
```

The mvc controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult ScopeFilterJavaScript()
    {
        return
File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/.../filterPartial.js")), "text/javascript");

    }
```

Because the user can only use one filter at a time and may or may not use multiple filters my questions are:

1. The scripts aren't big, is it better practice to load them all upfront rather then fetch them as required? The reason I load them as required is because they might not get called and didn't want to load a bunch of scripts that will not get used
2. Is not caching them a good idea because the user can use the same filter multiple times and in my current case the script will get loaded each time? OR should I rather cache the script and figure out a way not to load it again?
3. I'm also not 100% clear on script caching. What happens to the script in this case after it was loaded? If I make a call to the server I can see that it gets loaded again, was the previous scripts removed? Because when I look at the script tab on firebug they are all still listed there? Will this cause conflicts on the page?

What would best practice be in this scenario?

Thanks

*Edit: I've been researching the topic a bit further and found this article (Old but still very relevant in my opinion). [enter link description here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/)*

Comment: just a hint: removing scripts does not "unload" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's always a good idea to only load stuff if you actually need it. When the files arent that huge, maybe you can combine them and include them in the first place.
2. > OR should I rather cache the script and figure out a way not to load it again?

   yup.
3. When you load a script (without any queries) the browser caches it. But this has nothing to do with what happens when you load a script again. Either the servers delivers it "again" or the browser uses the cached one. Nevertheless, the script then executes again. Even if you remove it from the dom - once loaded scripts are just there.

Maybe you can wrap your scripts like so:

```
if (!window.foobarLoaded) {
  // your script content
  window.foobarLoaded = true;
}
```

Then you can load the script as many times as you like - it only "executes" once.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I saw an earlier post on testing for loaded scripts, and will use something like that.